# Placing Backbone Models in external files using node.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I'm trying to find my way through node.js and backbone.js. My intention is to share at least all model-states with the server and browser. Right now I'm not quite sure if I really need to share views as well. I also want to handle all routes by express and nodejs and not backbone. To keep my code a wee bit more structured I was looking forward to keep each model in a separate *.js file. By doing so I'm running into following error message:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'extend'
```

I thought it might be a problem with underscore missing in the separate file, so here is my basemodel:

models/BaseModel.js

```
var Backbone = require('../node_modules/backbone'),
_ = require('../node_modules/underscore'),

var BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  modelName: 'basemodel'

});

exports.BaseModel = BaseModel;
```

app.js
    var   BaseModel = require('./models/BaseModel');

```
var MyModel = BaseModel.extend({
// ... attributes, functions etc.

});
```

Does anyone have a hint what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: Read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549149/extending-the-defaults-of-a-model-superclass-in-backbone-js

Maybe it help?

Comment: Hey MrPovod, thanks for your reply. Not quite. I'm not even getting so far to work with attributes. If I place my BaseModel in app.js it works fine. Even if I output both BaseModel from BaseModel.js and BaseModel from app.js they seem both equal. Plus it DOES contain the extend function as well, but node.js complains about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. The flaw was in referencing to the BaseModel, so

this

```
var MyModel = BaseModel.extend({
  //
});
```

had to turn into:

```
var MyModel = BaseModel.BaseModel.extend({
   //
};
```

because of 
    exports.BaseModel = BaseModel;
in BaseModel.js

Answer (score 1):

Then try this code in app.js:

```
BaseModel = require('./models/BaseModel').BaseModel;
```

Or in models/BaseModel.js not of `exports.BaseModel = BaseModel;` use it - `module.exports = BaseModel`